# using cookies to store information about current web page

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter

I am new to web application development, I have a problem in verifying if a page that loads is  loaded for the first time or the page is refreshed. I understand that i am supposed to use cookies to store information about this page but i am having a very hard time doing that in javascript. Please assist

Comment: For current page only or for the current website? And what have you tried?

Comment: see section "The scripts" (read/write value to cookie): http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html

Comment: "I am having a very hard time doing that in javascript". So what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See here a very detailed explanation about how to use cookies in javascript

http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-deal-with-cookies-in-javascript/

Basically the easiest way is to create a getCookie and setCookie method and work with them

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to find page load, whether first time or not

```
If Not IsPostBack Then
    '' First time load
Else
    '' Again load same page
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you can use `session_start();` and then store a counter (or any other information about your current connection) in session and increment the counter each time the page is loaded.

```
session_start();
if(empty($_SESSION['counter']))
{
    //Page is requested first time.
    $_SESSION['counter'] = 1;
}
else
{
    //Page is not requested first time.
    $_SESSION['counter'] += 1;
}
```